# i had error while starting the cron job

Tags: magento2, cron, magento2.2.2, crontab, magento-cron

I had an error on starting cron job.
getting this error, now im unable to do anything in magento :(

```
Could not open input file: cron:run n:run
```

my cron job for magento is below,

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/time/bin/magento cron:run
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/time/update/cron.php
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/time/bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

whats wrong with this.?? kindly anyone help me.. to clear this error. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgot to install the cron job. Now, i had cleared the error. Problem solved by below command,

```
php bin/magento cron:install
```